# Django ORM: Filter on timedelta of Datetime fields

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation

I am trying to fetch posts based on the time difference of two `DateTimeField`s, say, posts that were deleted in less than 10 minutes after they were posted.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField()
    time_deleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

With the above model in hand, I tried;

```
from datetime import timedelta

Post.objects.exclude(deleted__isnull=True).annotate(
    delta=F('time_deleted') - F('time_posted')
).filter(delta__lt=timedelta(minutes=10))
```

and got a `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. Then I thought it may be the change of type (DateTime objects yielding Time object) so I tried it with `ExpressionWrapper`:

```
Post.objects.exclude(deleted__isnull=True).annotate(
    delta=models.ExpressionWrapper(
        F('time_deleted') - F('time_posted'), 
        output_field=models.TimeField())
    ).filter(delta__gt=timedelta(minutes=10))
```

But this caused the same exception too.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

According to @ivan's suggestion, I tried `DurationField()` instead. I no longer get the exception but the delta is always `0`.

```
>>> post = Post.objects.exclude(deleted__isnull=True).annotate(
        delta=ExpressionWrapper(F('deleted') - F('time'), 
        output_field=DurationField())
    ).first()
>>> post.time_posted
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 24, 13, 26, 50, 857326, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> post.time_deleted
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 24, 13, 27, 30, 521569, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> post.delta
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `models.DateTimeField()` as output_field ?

Comment: @LaundroMat @omat It is probably `models.DurationField` instead.

Comment: Yes, the 'DurationField' worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `output_field` kwarg should be [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField) instead, because it stores `datetime.timedelta` in Django, while `TimeField` stores `datetime.time`.

There is a caveat though:

> Arithmetic with DurationField works in most cases. However on all databases other than PostgreSQL, comparing the value of a DurationField to arithmetic on DateTimeField instances will not work as expected.

In the SQLite backend `DurationField` is represented by `bigint` which stores microseconds:

```
class DatabaseWrapper(BaseDatabaseWrapper):
    vendor = 'sqlite'
    # ...
    data_types = {
        # ...
        'DecimalField': 'decimal',
        'DurationField': 'bigint',
        'FileField': 'varchar(%(max_length)s)',
        # ...
    }
```

So because you are using SQLite you actually need `delta` to be a value in microseconds. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32686206/192390) for a `Func` which does that.

Comment: I no longer get the exception but the delta is always "0". Please see my edit in the questions. Thanks.

Comment: Sqlite on local development machine.

Comment: I will link to exactly your case.