# Django - calculate average of time between created_at and done_at

Tags: python, django

Lets say i have 100 objects in db and each object has `created_at` and `done_at` time. I want to calculate average of duration for all objects. Have idea like this: first to calculate durations of all objects and then get average. But is there other good way that will help?

Comment: you can also use the standard deviation as well have a look here  [link](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/9-django-tips-for-working-with-databases-beba787ed7d3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`aggregate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) and [`F` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for that:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, F

Model.objects.aggregate(average_delta=Avg(F('done_at') - F('created_at')))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. The problem is that i am using `sqlite3` and fields not as `date/time` saved as text. :/

Comment: Did not test this, but there seems to be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32686206/517560

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083091/8283848), You could try this also

```
from django.db.models import Avg, F

Model.objects.annotate(diff=F('done_at') - F('created_at')).aggregate(duration=Avg('diff'))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can't solve problem with converting string to datetime for avg

Comment: I think that's hard for you. Anyway try [Django Cast()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast)

Comment: Thanks alot, i did at first like you wrote but problem was that i have tried to cast it with `DateTimeField` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Jieter and Jerin Peter George answer made little changes and it works perfect:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, F, Sum, DurationField

IssueDone.objects.annotate(time_elapsed=Sum(Cast(F('done_date')-F('created_date'), DurationField()))).aggregate(Avg('time_elapsed'))
```